# scrolling overlay in silverlight

Tags: c#, scroll, overlay

I am using C#, Silverlight, WP7.

I have been going over Metro Grid Helper ([see this link](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/10/metrogridhelper/)) as I'm also interested in doing an overlay on an existing app. Basically I want to highlight an area, which would add a Rectangle on the overlay.

The difference is that I would like the overlay to scroll with the page, so that the Rectangle would stay in place over an item (like a TextBlock) underneath. And I am confused as to how to do it.

Any suggestions as to what methods or properties or events I should look into for this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am still learning how everything works in Silverlight, I figured this one out today.

The MetroGridHelper class that is linked in the original question adds the overlay objects to be children of the main Grid of the page. This means that no matter what the other controls are for the application (like a Pivot, Panorama, or ScrollViewer), the overlay objects will not move.

Thus, to get the objects to scroll (or swipe with a Pivot or Panorama), the objects need to be the children of the control. So inside the main Grid, look for the control and make that the parent of your objects.